# How check the data type of a value in a string?

Tags: c++

For example how can I check if the value in this string is `double`:

```
string a = "1.55"
```

or `int`:

```
string b = "2"
```

or "char"

```
string c = "b"
```

Comment: Time to learn regular expressions?

Comment: Take an existing C++ frontend and run it through that? (E.g. Clang)

Comment: A lot depends on your definition of data types. Are you talking about C++ data types? If so, your "char" example is incorrect. It should be `string c = "'b'"`.

Comment: I want to put the input in the `string` (for example a file). Then checking the variable type and put in the `string` in a suitable variable for the memory management (after converting the string to its atomic part).

Comment: @user1436187: I think you have a wrong understanding of C++ types. This is not PHP; you have to know a variable's type at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that your requirements are too vague, because **there is no 1:1 mapping between data types and string representations**.

What about `"2"`, for example? It could be a `double` as well as an `int` or even a `char`! What's worse, a `double` value of 2.0 may very well be represented as `"2"` rather than `"2.0"`.

And what about leading or trailing characters? Is `"2.0 "` a valid `double` or not? And `"2.0x"`? `"2.0 x`"?

So one has to answer your question with a counterquestion: What are you going to do with the type information gathered from the string? Or more precisely, what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

At any rate, I don't think that regular expression play any role in it. **String streams** look like a promising approach. The pattern is always more or less *try to convert the string, and if it fails then the string did not have the correct format*. A string may represent more than one type, so you have to choose which one takes precedence.

In order to be a bit more restrictive, you can check if the entire input string was used for the conversion. Here is a complete toy example with descriptive names :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
bool CanBeUsedToCreate(std::string const &string_representation)
{
    std::istringstream is(string_representation);
    T test_object;
    is >> test_object;
    bool const conversion_successful = !is.fail();
    bool const whole_string_used_for_conversion = is.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0;
    return conversion_successful && whole_string_used_for_conversion;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test_strings;
    test_strings.push_back("x");
    test_strings.push_back("2");
    test_strings.push_back("2.0");

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = test_strings.begin();
        iter != test_strings.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << *iter << "\" as double? " << (CanBeUsedToCreate<double>(*iter) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
        std::cout << "\"" << *iter << "\" as int? " << (CanBeUsedToCreate<int>(*iter) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
        std::cout << "\"" << *iter << "\" as char? " << (CanBeUsedToCreate<char>(*iter) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"x" as double? no
"x" as int? no
"x" as char? yes
"2" as double? yes
"2" as int? yes
"2" as char? yes
"2.0" as double? yes
"2.0" as int? no
"2.0" as char? no
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the string. Check `isalpha` if string holding `char` else  find `.`, if found, it is `double` (if the last character is not `f`) else `int`.

Comment: What about `1.55f`? Or `2LL`?

Comment: @juanchopanza; Still it will work. Program is searching `.`

Comment: `1.55f` is not `double`.

Comment: @juanchopanza; Got your point. But there are so many constraints can be imposed here.

Comment: `isalpha` is TRUE for for the 1.4f

Comment: `1.4f` is not a character. `isalpha` will not work. You just need to check only for first character of string.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on `C++11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    std::string x = argv [1];
    size_t pos = 0;
    bool isOk = true;

    try {
        stoi (x, & pos);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument) {
        isOk = false;
    }

    if ( (pos == x.length () ) && isOk) {
        std::cout << "Integer." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        isOk = true;
        try {
            stod (x, & pos);
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument) {
            isOk = false;
        }
        if ( (pos == x.length () ) && isOk) {
            std::cout << "Double." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "String." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./program 21  
Integer.  
$ ./program 21.22  
Double.  
$ ./program 21.22. 
String.  
$ ./program 21.22ddd  
String.  
$ ./program x21.22  
String.
```

Comment: It seems there is not an easy way!